# Express Validator - How to handle conditional Validation

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator, validator.js

I have a form where if a person's shipping address is different from their Billing address they will select a radio button saying "no".

I need to be able to check what the value of this is, and if it is "no" check the form that unfolds. if it is "yes" I skip on to the next validations below. The "yes section is working, but the "no" section always returns invalidated. is there a way to nest validations in a conditional like this with this library?

Here is a screenshot of the form:

[image: Test Form Image]

Here is the validation code i have for this scenario:

```
    router.post('/testData2/', [
      body('billingSameAsShipping', "Please Fill All Fields Of Your Billing Address").custom((value) => {
        if (value === 'no') {
          [
            body('billingFirstName', "Please Enter Your First Name").isLength({
              min: 1
            }),
            body('billingLastName', "Please Enter Your Last Name").isLength({
              min: 1
            }),
            body('billingAddress1', "Please Enter Your Billing Address").isLength({
              min: 1
            }),
            body('billingZip', "Please Enter Your Billing ZipCode").isLength({
              min: 1
            }),
            body('billingCity', "Please Enter Your Billing City").isLength({
              min: 1
            }),
            body('billingState', "Please Enter Your Billing State").isLength({
              min: 1
            })
          ]
        } else {

          return Promise.resolve();
        }

      }),
    body('creditCardNumber', 'Please Enter A Vaild Credit Card Number').isCreditCard(),
    body('expmonth', 'Exp Month Empty').isLength({
      min: 1
    }),
    body('expyear', 'Exp Year Empty').isLength({
      min: 1
    }),
    body('CVV', 'CVV Empty').isLength({
      min: 3
    })
  ],
  (req, res) => {...
```

Here is the request object we are checking against

```
{
  billingSameAsShipping: 'no',
  billingFirstName: 'First',
  billingLastName: 'Last',
  billingAddress1: '450 Test Ave',
  billingZip: '12345',
  billingCity: 'San Diego',
  billingState: 'CA',
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it, Express Validator has a conditional check built-in

I used oneOf([]) to check if the value of the radio buttons was "yes" **or** check that the billing address fields were filled in.

```
router.post('/testData2/', [
    oneOf([
      [
        body('billingFirstName', "Please Enter Your First Name").isLength({
          min: 1
        }),
        body('billingLastName', "Please Enter Your Last Name").isLength({
          min: 1
        }),
        body('billingAddress1', "Please Enter Your Billing Address").isLength({
          min: 1
        }),
        body('billingZip', "Please Enter Your Billing ZipCode").isLength({
          min: 1
        }),
        body('billingCity', "Please Enter Your Billing City").isLength({
          min: 1
        }),
        body('billingState', "Please Enter Your Billing State").isLength({
          min: 1
        })
      ],
      body('billingSameAsShipping').equals('yes')
    ], "Please Fill Out All Fields Of Your Billing Address"),
    body('creditCardNumber', 'Please Enter A Vaild Credit Card Number').isCreditCard(),
    body('expmonth', 'Exp Month Empty').isLength({
      min: 1
    }),
    body('expyear', 'Exp Year Empty').isLength({
      min: 1
    }),
    body('CVV', 'CVV Empty').isLength({
      min: 3
    })
  ],
  (req, res) => {...
```

That seems to be working correctly now.

Anyone have any other solutions to this one, or see anything wrong with my solution above?

Comment: i'm using custom validators which helps me to easier parse the errors on client side


`body("billingFirstName") .custom((value, { req }) => { return req.body.billingSameAsShipping === 'yes' ? true : value }) .isLength({ min: 1 }) .withMessage("Please Enter Your First Name")`

Comment: Hi Timothy, I hope you still around as I need help with oneO(), Your answer allowed me to check for the condition but I get an error that  node_modules\express-validator\src\middlewares\check.js:19 next(e); In my endpoint I check the results like so :   const ValidationResults = validationResult(req)
     console.log(" error :", ValidationResults.array())

Comment: error : [
  {
    msg: Promise { <pending> },
    param: '_error',
    nestedErrors: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]             I see that the promise is pending but I don't know how to fix that? How did you handle the promise in the endpoint?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [this conditional](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#ifcondition) which allows to do stuff like:

```js
body('billingFirstName').if(body('billingSameAsShipping').equals('yes')).notEmpty(),
```

and the sort

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to turn validators conditional. The condition is a `boolean`, so you can simply use the `&&` logical operator to decide whether to add a validator to the array or not.

```
router.post('/testData2/', [

   req.body.billingSameAsShipping && body('billingFirstName')
      .isLength({ min: 1 }),

   req.body.billingSameAsShipping && body('billingLastName')
      .isLength({ min: 1 })

   ].filter(x => !!x)
)
```

The filter at the end is needed because if the condition evaluates to `false`, it will add `false` to the array. That would cause a runtime error, so it has to be removed. This is the most concise way to add validators conditionally.

Comment: This seems to be incorrect. I wonder how you are getting the context of `req` object for comparisons when its not a Middleware at all.