# Validate an array property only if another property inside the same object is true with express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using express-validator to validate the requests to my express application and I have one endpoint that receives one object in which one of the properties is an array of objects. It looks like this below.

```
{
    "propA": "",
    "propB": "",
    "items": [
         {
              "enabled": true,
              "name": "",
              "icon": "",
         }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to set the name and icon as `required` only if the `enabled` property is set to `true`.

I tried to do something like this, but I doesn't work as expected.

```
  body("items").isArray().withMessage("Items format is invalid"),
  body("items.*.enabled").isBoolean(),
  body("items.*.name").if(body("items.*.enabled")).notEmpty().bail(),
  body("items.*.icon").if(body("items.*.enabled")).notEmpty().bail()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express Validator - How to handle conditional Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600073/express-validator-how-to-handle-conditional-validation)

Comment: No, it didn't work. Probably because I'm using properties inside an array. I think express-validator is checking it as whole instead of looking it per object when I use oneOf.

Comment: Perhaps a custom validation here might be the only option? via `custom`.

Comment: Yes, it was the only options. Project maintainers said it's not possible within the current version. Plans to improve this on version 7.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to do this in express-validator's version I'm using (6.12.1). I had to write a custom function and use validator.js functions (which is used by express-validator) manually.

https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/1126

Maintainers are planning to improve this on version 7.0.0.